# bitcoin.conf location on Mac with Bitcoin Core v25 ("Error: Prune mode is incompatible with -txindex")

Tags: mac, pruning, bitcoin.conf, txindex, ordinals

**TLDR**: where can `bitcoin.conf` be found on Mac running Bitcoin Core v25?

**Context**:
I have Bitcoin Core v25 on Mac and run into a "*Error: Prune mode is incompatible with -txindex*" when opening the Application. Before closing the app, I had set the a parameter `txindex=1` in `bitcoin.conf` using the GUI, as well as selecting pruning.

Now that I cannot access the GUI because of the error message, I'm unclear how to work around this issue.
I've looked at past posts and it isn't clear where `bitcoin.conf` lives on Mac.

I've checked the files in `/Applications/Bitcoin-Qt.app/Contents`.

I was following the guideline from the Inscriptions Ordinals handbook: https://docs.ordinals.com/guides/inscriptions.html

Comment: I ran `find / -name "bitcoin.conf" 2>/dev/null` and found 2 files with `bitcoin.conf`. After editing them to remove the `txindex` parameter, the Bitcoin Core Application is still returning the issue.

Comment: If you want to use ord, why would you want to remove txindex?

Comment: This was a mistake, I shouldn't have selected pruning. Now I'm unable to open the Bitcoin Core app (GUI and CLI)

Comment: Unmount all network and external drives and run `sudo grep -ri txindex / &> /Users/.../Desktop/list`

Comment: Thanks, I did that and found 4 matches which also contain "bitcoin" in the file name. These are binary files and opened them with Hex Fiend. Unclear what's required next...